# Parsing JSON from string to an object

Tags: javascript, json

**UPDATE**
bone headed move on my part - was saving from the client incorrectly (via iOS).

Thank you for suggestions.

**Original**

I am trying to parse a JSON object... not sure how to go about doing it in JS? The object keeps coming in with:

- "=" instead of ":"
- ";" instead of ","
- "(" instead of "["

how can I convert this to format properly?

I tried `var y = JSON.stringify(x); JSON.parse(y);` but it's resulting in undefined.

```
   var x =  (
       {
         var_1 = ABCD;
         var_2 = "K123";
         var_3 = JsnHugg;
        },
        {
         var_1 = EFGH;
         var_2 = "K345";
         var_3 = SKSKSKS;
        },
        {
         var_1 = IJKL;
         var_2 = "K678";
         var_3 = ZKSFHG;
        }
    )):
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: That's not valid javascript. Have you even bothered to look at the console for errors?

Comment: You get it as undefined because your entry data is not a valid JSON

Comment: Apologies - I understand it is not a valid json - when I call it from the DB - it comes In with this format. Is it possible to convert to a proper json?

Comment: You need to parse it to a proper object on the serverside. Most languages have a json library and it would be more of a pain to do it as it stands than to just do it properly when you get it from the database.

Comment: can you provide more details on how are you getting this ? is this what you find in the console ? what's the backend written in ? can you post the raw object you are receiving ? ( without x = ... ) , is it a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want `x` to be an array of objects: enclose them in square brackets, not parentheses. Also, assign properties to values with `:`, and use commas rather than semicolons at the end of a declaration inside an object:

```js
var x = [
  {
    var_1: 'ABCD',
    var_2: "K123",
    var_3: 'JsnHugg',
  },
  {
    var_1: 'EFGH',
    var_2: "K345",
    var_3: 'SKSKSKS',
  },
  {
    var_1: 'IJKL',
    var_2: "K678",
    var_3: 'ZKSFHG',
  }
];
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)));
```

Comment: Apologies - I understand the item in my question is not a valid json - this is how it is coming in when I call it from the DB.. Is it possible to convert to a proper json "=" -> ":", "(" -> "[" etc?

Comment: The object values are invalid as well (I had to convert them to strings). Try fixing your endpoint first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
var x = [
       {
         var_1 : "ABCD",
         var_2 : "K123",
         var_3 : "JsnHugg"
        },
        {
         var_1 : "EFGH",
         var_2 : "K345",
         var_3 : "SKSKSKS"
        },
        {
         var_1 : "IJKL",
         var_2 : "K678",
         var_3 : "ZKSFHG"
        }
    ];
```

Comment: This is invalid JSON.

Comment: Congrats that's also invalid

Comment: This is valid Javascript, but not valid JSON. In JSON, object keys must be quoted.